# WebAPI File upload function with parameters called from c# desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a c# desktop application that makes calls a WebAPI.  One function uploads a file and has parameters.

I have found examples that use MultipartFormDataContent but I can't get that to work if there are parameters in the call.

How do you set up the PostAsync to have both MultiFormDataContent and url parameters in the content and not embedding them as part of the requestURI?

API Functions

```
    //Can Call this
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadFileTest")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileTest()
    {...

    //How to do this
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadFileTest")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileTest(string toolToken)
    {...
```

C# calling it

```
    //this works with the first API call
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("www.someURL/APICalls/");
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), "\"file\"", string.Format("\"{0}\"", fileInfo.Name));
    //adding the following line doesn't work with the second API function, it can't find the API function to call.
    //content.Add(new StringContent("12345"), "toolToken");

    Task taskUpload = client.PostAsync("UploadFileTest", content).ContinueWith(task =>
    {...
```

Answer (score 0):

try `[FromBody]`

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadFileTest")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileTest([FromBody]string toolToken)
{...
```

Comment: That throws an API Internal Server Error  responce body.  And I would like to use the existing function, as it is used by other web calls.

Comment: `API Internal Server Error responce body` - it's problem when you create responce which should be send to the client.

Comment: What do you mean by `existing function`? You don't want to add attribute?

Comment: @runfastman, please, try to read this  [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding/) . You should find there are what you are looking for. Do not forget post your solution :)

Comment: I have an API function "UploadFile" with parameters without [FromBody] in it, that is currently in use.  I could make a new function but I would prefer not to duplicate code.

Comment: So from what I read and some other looking, you can have only one type of content on a PostAsync, if I want to have URI and Body parameters, I have to pass the URI parameters in as a string on the requestURI.